# password not working in node-telnet-client

Tags: node.js, telnet

I am using node-telnet-client to connect to a server. But the server needs a password for creating a connection. I tried including password property in the params object but no success.

var params = {
  host: '10.97.42.172',
  port: 23,
  shellPrompt: '/ # ',
  password:1,
  timeout: 10000,
  // removeEcho: 4 
}

connection.connect(params)

Comment: use passwordPrompt instead of password. if it didnt work try passing a string in password field.

Comment: I tried passwordPromt as well. same result. it's getting timed out and then close everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 2323,
  shellPrompt: '/ # ',
  loginPrompt: 'Username: ',
  passwordPrompt: 'Password: ',
  username: 'foo',
  password: 'bar',
  initialLFCR: true,
  timeout: 1500
}
```

This would help you to connect to your server. 
Notice that the password is a string. 
Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: i'm not getting any error. it's entering into timeout and then close state. i have set my timeout to 5000 ms

Comment: how can i know the shellPrompt that is been used?? @aswin